# Audit shows actual author

Tags: bug, low-quality-posts

Today when I was going through LQP Queue, this particular audit came up. The problem is that the answer showed up with the actual user (with their rep and avatar unchanged). Now, the rep clearly gives away that they are an experienced user. So even before I read the answer I had assumed someone had flagged the answer by mistake. I assume it would be pretty hard for anyone else to fail this audit as well.

In the past, when I have encountered such audits, I have noticed that fake users with very low rep are used in place of the actual user. So I am not sure if this particular audit was a bug, or the feature of faking the user rep hasn't been implemented in the LQP queue. Hopefully someone can look into it.

[image]

Comment: I've seen this before (at least twice) but assumed it was on purpose.

Comment: To be fair, I've also seen legit non-answers from high rep users in the LQP too. They're usually very old though, probably from when they first started on the site.

Comment: Usually, it fuzzes the author while you're looking at the audit, and then reveals it after you've completed the audit. That's consistent with your screenshot. Are you *certain* that it showed Jeremy's user card *before* you made a selection?

Comment: @CodyGray Yup, the author name and rep was there before I clicked "Looks OK". And, yup, normally the correct author's name (or rep) is not shown before the reviewer acts on it. That's why I posted here.

Comment: Side note: unfortunately reputation of a user has nothing to do with quality of questions... While @BSMP comment that most such questions are old is valid there are enough users that just ask about anything they see and gain decent rep from occasional gems... Sometimes you feel that you  follow a person that reads through a book and asks questions that would be answered on next page if they care to read before asking.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov Yup I am aware. But I have also observed that high rep users are extremely unlikely to do something silly. Plus this one was an answer - not a question. It is much easier to fall for MCVE or "too broad" trap in questions than NAA for answers.

Comment: *"But I have also observed that high rep users are extremely unlikely to do something silly."* Oh, would if that were true!